# Install multiple Linux OS using WUBI

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, linux-mint

I want to install Linux Mint, and Ubuntu on my laptop using Wubi installation. I already installed Ubuntu, but when I launch the Wubi installer for Mint. I got this guy:
[image]

Does it mean to say that I can only install one os using the wubi? Do you know of any solution to this problem, except by  installing mint using the usual way. I have XP and Windows 7 installed on the machine. That's why I'm using Wubi so that I won't get into troubles.

Comment: Check here, should to the trick:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/129149/how-to-enable-booting-multiple-ubuntu-wubi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wubi is a Ubuntu install for Windows only. It is not meant for Mint nor does it look like there will be a "Wubi for Mint" anytime soon. I know, I'm pretty disappointed about that, too.

[See this thread](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=9818) for more details.

Comment: As you can see in my screenshot, it was mint4win. Its similar to Wubi. And I installed Mint inside windows before. It was mint 9 to be exact.

Comment: Since Mint is basically just Ubuntu modified for more convenience, I suppose what you're trying to do is like installing an XP Media Center alongside a regular XP Home Edition installation with an automated installer that only recognize both of them as identical OS. So, yes, it's impossible. Besides, Mint offers all Ubuntu can offer, with few nice touch here and there. I would just go along with Mint.

Comment: @soul: Well you can't install both, they're basically the same core system.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to download and install the Windows version of Virtual Box (free from Source Forge or other reputable download sites). Assuming you have sufficient HD space, you can create a virtual machine while in Windows for one or more systems. Then you can have one for Ubuntu and another for Mint. You can boot either from Windows and switch around without rebooting the system as you do with Wubi or Mint4Win install. There might be a some limitations using virtual box, but I don't recall which at the moment.